Unable find an ffmpeg binary for your Android system
Working on a project where I need to use FFmpeg library in Kotlin to work on some audio files. However I'm unable to initialize the ffmpeg library itself.
this is the error I'm getting
Could not find an ffmpeg binary for your Android system. Did you forget calling: 'new AndroidFFMPEGLocator(this);' ?
2024-07-22 18:48:33.910 11800-11800 PipeDecoder             com.example.sangeet                  E  Tried to unpack a statically compiled ffmpeg binary for your architecture to: /data/user/0/com.example.sangeet/cache/ffmpeg
2024-07-22 18:48:33.923 11800-11800 AndroidRuntime          com.example.sangeet                  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.sangeet, PID: 11800
                                                                                                    java.lang.Error: Decoding via a pipe will not work: Could not find an ffmpeg binary for your system

@HiltAndroidApp
class Sangeet: Application(){
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        provideFirebaseApp(this)
        FFmpegKitConfig.setLogLevel(Level.AV_LOG_INFO)
        FFmpegKitConfig.enableLogCallback { Log.d("ffmpeg",it.message) }
        initializeFFmpegKit()
    }
    private fun initializeFFmpegKit() {
        // This method should be sufficient to ensure FFmpegKit is ready to use
        val ffmpegSession = FFmpegKit.execute("ffmpeg -version")
        if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(ffmpegSession.returnCode)) {
            Log.d("FFmpeg", "FFmpeg is ready to use.")
        } else {
            Log.e("FFmpeg", "Failed to initialize FFmpeg: ${ffmpegSession.failStackTrace}")
            initializeFFmpegBinary()
        }
    }
    private fun initializeFFmpegBinary() {
        val ffmpegBinaryPath = filesDir.absolutePath + "/ffmpeg"
        val binaryFile = File(ffmpegBinaryPath)
        if (!binaryFile.exists()) {
            Log.e("FFmpeg", "FFmpeg binary not found at $ffmpegBinaryPath")
            // Copy or download the FFmpeg binary to this path
        } else {
            Log.d("FFmpeg", "FFmpeg binary found at $ffmpegBinaryPath")
        }
    }
}

Tried using AndroidFFMPEGLocator(this); as suggested by the compiler in my code but unknown reference error is coming for the above line of code.
Also tried using FFmpegKit.init(this) function but init is also not being recognised by the compiler

The error message tells you to call AndroidFFMPEGLocator(this) -- did you? Please [edit] your question and add this information.

@Leviathan i've answered your question in my edited answer
